# Unity animation setting bool true but doesnt set false after setting true?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

Everything matches at unity like controller name , parameter name vs. but my animation after i set it true, doesnt set false.Here is code:

```
    public Animator anim;


void Start()
{
    anim = gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>();

}


void Update()
{

    if (this.GetComponent<cube2>().enabled)
    {
        

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            anim.SetBool("tikk", false);
           
        }
        else
        {
            anim.SetBool("tikk", true);
        }
    }
    

}
```

Comment: Maybe you want to use `Input.GetMouseButton(0)` instead of `Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)` (the first is true while the mouse button is down, the second one only for the first frame)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a check if not input.getmousebuttondown and switching the booleans.